# jquery aTooltip still displays after .remove

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am using the aTooltip plugin

```
<a href="#" id="a_id" onclick="deletethis();return false;" class="normalTip" title="delete this">some text</a>
```

the deletethis() function is simply:

```
$('#a_id').remove();
```

after removing the element the tooltip still appears. Is there a way to hide it manually after the .remove statement?

here is the aToolTip plugin code. From http://itsmeara.com/jquery/atooltip/

```
/*
    jQuery Version:             jQuery 1.3.2+
    Plugin Name:                aToolTip V 1.5
    Plugin by:                  Ara Abcarians: http://ara-abcarians.com
    License:                    aToolTip is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License
                                Read more about this license at --> http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/         
*/
(function($) {
    $.fn.aToolTip = function(options) {
        /**
            setup default settings
        */
        var defaults = {
            // no need to change/override
            closeTipBtn: 'aToolTipCloseBtn',
            toolTipId: 'aToolTip',
            // ok to override
            fixed: false,
            clickIt: false,
            inSpeed: 200,
            outSpeed: 100,
            tipContent: '',
            toolTipClass: 'defaultTheme',
            xOffset: 5,
            yOffset: 5,
            onShow: null,
            onHide: null
        },
        // This makes it so the users custom options overrides the default ones
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            /**
                Decide weather to use a title attr as the tooltip content
            */
            if(obj.attr('title')){
                // set the tooltip content/text to be the obj title attribute
                var tipContent = obj.attr('title');  
            } else {
                // if no title attribute set it to the tipContent option in settings
                var tipContent = settings.tipContent;
            }

            /**
                Build the markup for aToolTip
            */
            var buildaToolTip = function(){
                $('body').append("<div id='"+settings.toolTipId+"' class='"+settings.toolTipClass+"'><p class='aToolTipContent'>"+tipContent+"</p></div>");

                if(tipContent && settings.clickIt){
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId+' p.aToolTipContent')
                    .append("<a id='"+settings.closeTipBtn+"' href='#' alt='close'>close</a>");
                }
            },
            /**
                Position aToolTip
            */
            positionaToolTip = function(){
                $('#'+settings.toolTipId).css({
                    top: (obj.offset().top - $('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset) + 'px',
                    left: (obj.offset().left + obj.outerWidth() + settings.xOffset) + 'px'
                })
                .stop().fadeIn(settings.inSpeed, function(){
                    if ($.isFunction(settings.onShow)){
                        settings.onShow(obj);
                    }
                });             
            },
            /**
                Remove aToolTip
            */
            removeaToolTip = function(){
                // Fade out
                $('#'+settings.toolTipId).stop().fadeOut(settings.outSpeed, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                    if($.isFunction(settings.onHide)){
                        settings.onHide(obj);
                    }
                });             
            };

            /**
                Decide what kind of tooltips to display
            */
            // Regular aToolTip
            if(tipContent && !settings.clickIt){    
                // Activate on hover    
                obj.hover(function(){
                    // remove already existing tooltip
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId).remove();
                    obj.attr({title: ''});
                    buildaToolTip();
                    positionaToolTip();
                }, function(){ 
                    removeaToolTip();
                }); 
            }           

            // Click activated aToolTip
            if(tipContent && settings.clickIt){
                // Activate on click    
                obj.click(function(el){
                    // remove already existing tooltip
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId).remove();
                    obj.attr({title: ''});
                    buildaToolTip();
                    positionaToolTip();
                    // Click to close tooltip
                    $('#'+settings.closeTipBtn).click(function(){
                        removeaToolTip();
                        return false;
                    });      
                    return false;           
                });
            }

            // Follow mouse if enabled
            if(!settings.fixed && !settings.clickIt){
                obj.mousemove(function(el){
                    $('#'+settings.toolTipId).css({
                        top: (el.pageY - $('#'+settings.toolTipId).outerHeight() - settings.yOffset),
                        left: (el.pageX + settings.xOffset)
                    });
                });         
            }           

        }); // END: return this
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

After

$('#a_id').remove();

Execute

$('#aToolTip').remove();

Comment: #aToolTip invokes the aToolTip function? Isn't it just for ids?

Comment: I din't understood you correctly, but the Tooltip is a div with id "aToolTip", hence i suggested to remove the tooltip div :)